# Shifting columns by date match pandas

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a Dataframe that looks like:

```
# Identifier  DATE       RDATE      X Y Z
#  1         1990-08-29 1990-04-30  1 2 3
#  1         1990-09-29 1990-04-30  1 2 3
#  1         1990-10-29 1990-07-30  3 5 7
#  2         1990-11-29 1990-07-30  2 1 4
#  2         1990-12-29 1990-10-30  2 1 5
#  3         1990-05-29 1990-01-30  1 2 3
#  3         1990-06-29 1990-04-30  4 4 4
#  3         1990-07-29 1990-04-30  4 4 4
#  3         1990-08-29 1990-06-30  1 1 1
```

Basically what I would like to do is to shift the columns RDATE, X, Y, Z of the dataframe such that the column RDATE is always the closest date that occurs before the date in column DATE while respecting the identifier. Note that some of the dates in DATE occur several times for the different identifiers.

I assume the solution would require me to groupby the identifier, which I am able to do. My problem lies in comparing column DATE with RDATE and then shifting the other columns based on the location.

That is, my expected output would be:

```
# Identifier  DATE       RDATE      X Y Z
#  1         1990-08-29 1990-07-30  3 5 7
#  1         1990-09-29 1990-07-30  3 5 7
#  1         1990-10-29 1990-07-30  3 5 7
#  2         1990-11-29 1990-10-30  2 1 5
#  2         1990-12-29 1990-10-30  2 1 5
#  3         1990-05-29 1990-04-30  4 4 4
#  3         1990-06-29 1990-04-30  4 4 4
#  3         1990-07-29 1990-06-30  1 1 1
#  3         1990-08-29 1990-06-30  1 1 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [merge_asof](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html):

```
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])
df['RDATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['RDATE'])

result = pd.merge_asof(df[['Identifier', 'DATE']].sort_values('DATE'), df[['Identifier', 'RDATE', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']].sort_values('RDATE'), left_on='DATE', right_on='RDATE', by='Identifier').sort_values(['Identifier','DATE']).reset_index(drop=True)
result
#   Identifier       DATE      RDATE  X  Y  Z
#0           1 1990-08-29 1990-07-30  3  5  7
#1           1 1990-09-29 1990-07-30  3  5  7
#2           1 1990-10-29 1990-07-30  3  5  7
#3           2 1990-11-29 1990-10-30  2  1  5
#4           2 1990-12-29 1990-10-30  2  1  5
#5           3 1990-05-29 1990-04-30  4  4  4
#6           3 1990-06-29 1990-04-30  4  4  4
#7           3 1990-07-29 1990-06-30  1  1  1
#8           3 1990-08-29 1990-06-30  1  1  1
```

Comment: @Chris So this sorting is okay with you?